# How to estimate norms involving $|a-b|$?

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity, normed-spaces

I know the title isn't the best one.

Here's my problem:

Whenever I'm given functionals such as:

$$\phi: \mathcal{C}^1([0,1]) \ni f \rightarrow f(\frac{1}{3}) - f'(\frac{2}{3}) \in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)| + \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f'(t)|$$

or

$$\phi: \mathcal{C}^1([0,1]) \ni f \rightarrow \int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt - f'(\frac{2}{3}) \in \mathbb{R}, \ \ \|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)|$$

or

$$\phi : \mathcal{C}^1([0,1]) \ni f \rightarrow \{f(0) - f(\frac{1}{n+1})\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \in \mathcal{c}_0, \ \ \|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)|$$

and asked to find their norm, if they turn out to be bounded,

that is, whenever I have a difference while calculating the norm $\|\phi (f)\|$, for example in the first case: $\|\phi (f)\| = |f(\frac{1}{3}) - f'(\frac{2}{3})| $ there's no way I can get an optimal constant $M>0$ such that $\|\phi(f)\| \le M \|f\|$ by using triangle inequality (preceded by mean value theorem in the second example).

But nothing else comes to mind.

What can I do then?

Comment: Use $|a - b| \leq |a| + |b|$. That alone won't give you an optimal constant, but it shows it is at least bounded.

Comment: Fine, but then I get, in the last example, $||\phi (f)|| \le |f(0)| + ||f|| \le 2 ||f||$, so I need to find $f$ such that $\sup|f(0) - f(1/(n+1)| = 2 \sup |f(x)|$. Will I find it?

Comment: Or in the first example, if the triangle inequality method sufficed, I would need $f$ such that $|f(\frac{1}{3}) - f'(\frac{2}{3})| = \|f\| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f(t)| + \sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f'(t)|$

Comment: If you want to find an optimal constant for the first, yes, you would need $f$ such that $\sup |f| = f(1/3), \sup|f'| = -f'(2/3)$. Something along the lines of $f = 1$ if $x < 1/2$, $f = 1-2x$ for $x \geq 1/2$ (and then smoothed at $x = 1/2$) would work.

Comment: In the second example, the functional is not bounded; the value of the functional depends on the value of the derivative, but the norm of the function in this case does not. You can easily come up with a sequence of functions that has constant sup norm, but has a bigger and bigger derivative (think of a narrow spike near $x = 2/3$).

Comment: For the third one, $f = 1 - 2x$ works. In general, it might not be easy to come up with a function attaining the optimal constant, you may have to resort to a sequence of functions, or a more indirect method, or you simply might not be able to determine one.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.